How to get my money back I put down on a purchase and never received item
I sent someone $100 on cash app to hold a camper until I got down there to get it per her request. She then blocked me on everything even cash app and will not even give me an address. What can I do I have screenshots of the entire conversation then of her cursing me for requesting her to return my money. Can I make some kind of charges against her?

It will be very relevant where this did happen, and also where that person lives. You tagged this 10th amendment, which suggests the US, but why would that amendment matter here?

I suspect there never was a camper, although there may have been some nice photos.

It might be a breach of contract you could sue, in theory, over
If at the time the $100 was provided there was a camper and the person on the app was really going to sell it to you, but then they changed their mind and broke their promise (perhaps because the camper was damaged or stolen or someone offered a higher price for it), then that person has breached a contract, but has not committed a crime.
The downside to that is that you need someone's real name and some way for a process server to deliver legal papers to them to sue them. Even then, it may not be cost effective to sue someone for $100 given the trouble it would take to locate who they are and where they can be sued. It might be possible to get this information with a subpoena served upon the the cash app operator, but the information provided to the cash app operator might have been false and that would be a cumbersome process. In the U.S. you could recover the $100 not repaid with interest and your out of pocket court costs including a process server's costs, but not your attorneys' fees and the time and effort you devoted to pursuing the case. It would be hard to press the case without a lawyer. But it would not be cost effective to hire a lawyer.
On the other hand, if you'd paid $15,000 instead of $100 for the camper, it might be worth the trouble to hire a lawyer and pursue the case by obtaining the cash app operator's information about the perpetrator, in a lawsuit which could also include a claim in the alternative for fraud or theft which could make it possible to recover something beyond the amount of money you lost, interest, and your court costs. Or, it might be worth hiring a private investigator to try to find the person you dealt with, to facilitate a lawsuit or criminal complaint to law enforcement.
In most places outside the U.S., however, you could also recover at least some of your attorneys' fees if you won the case.
It was probably a crime
As Weather Vane notes in a comment:

I suspect there never was a camper, although there may have been some
nice photos.

If, instead, the person intended to rip you off in the first place, and maybe there never even was a camper, then you were defrauded and a crime was committed. You are the victim of theft or criminal fraud. But, again, unless law enforcement or the prosecutor's office can learn the real name of the culprit and some way to locate that person, that person will never been arrested or charged with a crime.
Usually, though, law enforcement and the prosecutor's office won't be willing to make the effort necessary to catch a thief in this situation over a $100 theft, particularly when it is possible that it was a non-criminal breach of contract rather than an actual fraud. It is impossible to tell whether it was a breach of contract or a fraud from the facts known to you for sure. This is by design. Someone engaged in fraud wants to set up the transaction so that it might not be a crime at all, in order to discourage law enforcement from doing anything.
If found guilty, maybe the perpetrator would owe a few hundred dollars in fines and court costs, a hundred dollars of restitution, and would face a few days in jail or a short period of probation. If a conviction wasn't certain, that might be plea bargained to returning the $100 and paying a small fine, or to a non-fraud based charge that would have fewer long term consequences for them if it had to be disclosed in a background check (e.g. criminal vandalism in the same dollar amount instead of fraud).
The possibility of an insurance claim
One reason to make a police report is that you might be able to make an insurance claim if you have a very low deductible on your theft insurance policy (often part of a homeowner's insurance or renter's insurance policy), and if you can convince the adjuster somehow that this was fraud and not just a broken promise.
For example, if the name on the cash app account was someone who died a couple of years ago, you can be pretty sure that it was theft and not a mere breach of contract.
For $100 loss, this is probably cold comfort because your deductible is probably larger than your claim. But if you lost, for example, $2,000, and could show enough evidence to persuade an insurance adjuster that it was fraud, you could probably recover some of your losses with an insurance claim.
Credit cards leave you with options that cash apps don't
If you had paid via a credit card, instead of via a cash app, the credit card company could have reversed the charges. All you would have to show is that you didn't get your money back, not that you were defrauded.
So, if you are engaged in this kind of transaction, you should be wary of someone who wants you to use a cash app rather than a credit card.
The possibility of organizing a collective response
In the somewhat similar case of bicycles that are stolen and then resold on eBay or similar online forums, sometimes a group of bicyclists will get together and pool their resources since they have lots of victims of the same people and lots of likely future victims, and they will investigate until they find enough details about the perpetrators to hand a much bigger dollar case involving a scheme to steal hundreds of bicycles wrapped up in a bow and delivered on a silver platter to law enforcement.
Canvasing other people to see if anyone else was a victim of something similar could put together a case like this one, if it really is an organized fraud campaign. But you'd be doing it as much for revenge and to prevent this menace to online commerce from continuing to defraud people as you would be to personally benefit from the effort economically. You'd probably lose even more time and money than you already have, but you might feel good about it and make some friends and restore your faith in humanity a little by trying.


Can I make some kind of charges against her?

Sure.
If you think you have been illegally wronged, you can go to the police and tell them what happend. You do not need to know any identities other than your own and you certainly don't need a law degree to determine what the appropriate charge would be.
The police will take your report and determine if a crime has happend and will then proceed to investigate and give the results to the DA to prosecute.
If indeed it is found no crime happened, assuming you told the truth in your report, you should have no repercussions.
This is how any legal system should work. However, I can only guarantee that for germany. But society would crumble if only people who can identify the perpetrator and have a law degree to determine what the actual crime is to charge them with can get help. I would assume that every sane country on earth works this way, where Joe Random can walk up to the police and get help when they suspect they have been victim of a crime.
Whether the police can actually do anything in your case, that depends on a lot of factors. You may indeed never see that money again.

You can’t
You’ve been defrauded. The chances of ever finding this person are slim to none.
On the plus side, it only cost you $100 to learn a very valuable lesson.
Also, people don’t fall for scams because they’re stupid; they fall for scams because they’re people. Anyone who gets through their life never being conned isn’t clever, they’re lucky.
